# What does drop a stitch mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> “But they’re such fierce competition for university places they can’t
>   afford to **drop a stitch**, can they?” ([BBC Radio Drama, The
>   Archers](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/?page=2))

(1) What does the highlighted part mean?
(2) Is university places in UK a kind of entrance exam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Drop a stitch” is a term from knitting ([1](http://www.stitchdiva.com/tutorials/knitting/dropping-stitches),[2](http://knitting.about.com/od/troubleshooting/f/dropped_stitch.htm),[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-stitch_knitting)).  It is often used as a metaphor for making a mistake.  (But note that drop-stitch knitting also is used on purpose to make designs.)

“University places” refers not to an exam, but instead to openings or positions for students.  Prestigious universities typically have several times as many applicants as they have places for. The general idea is that a single mistake might knock someone out of the running.