# What does "a drop in replacement" mean

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Please see the second response [here](http://blog.thetys-retz.net/post/2010/11/01/Importing-Ubuntu-Font-Family-in-LaTeX).

> You should try xelatex which is almost a drop in replacement for
>   latex.

Leaving aside the technical part, which of no interest to the general audience here, I am interested in knowing what does this "almost a drop in replacement" mean?

I have a general feeling that this means something which will eventually/easily replace something, but I may be wrong.

We have other questions ([A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/what-does-drop-of-an-opinion-mean), [B](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/what-does-drop-a-stitch-mean)) here on "drop", but they seem to be different.

Comment: The correct phrase is `drop-in replacement`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not (a drop) (in) (replacement), but rather (a) (drop in) (replacement).

It is such a good replacement that you could take away the original, *drop in* the replacement, and not notice it. Well, *almost*, according to the text.

Comment: I searched google for the meaning of "drop-in" and what meaning I got is "visited on an informal basis without booking or appointments." And that meaning don't work here. So I am curious to known where from you got this meaning.

Comment: From usage. And yes, there are other meanings as well. Actually when I look on google, by far most of the links on the first page for **drop in replacement** fit the meaning I gave. I am actually wondering how much you tried to find an alternative, completely non-fitting menaning. Have a look at our neighbours at [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48748/is-sans-a-drop-in-replacement-for-without).

Comment: Only one I found - https://www.wordnik.com/words/drop-in

Comment: If you type _define drop in replacement_ into google you will find tons of examples that use it in the sense that I explained :)

Comment: There are two meanings of "drop in" that come to mind, and you've hit on them both. There is "drop in [to some place]", meaning to visit without booking. And there is "drop [something] in [to replace something else]", which is less common, except in idioms like "drop-in replacement".

Comment: I'd differentiate it differently... 'drop in' to perform the act of visiting or inserting, verb. 'drop-in' The place to visit [drop-in centre], or object to be inserted [drop-in replacement], noun.

Answer (score 6):

This is something of a technical idiom. If you have a system of parts (e.g. a home computer), and you can pick up one module (e.g. a RAM stick) and "drop in" a new one in its place without fiddling about (because the connections are the same and the two sticks are the same size), then the new RAM stick is a "drop-in replacement" for the old one.

The phrase has since been transplanted from the physical realm into the virtual one, where a piece of software or a piece of code or really anything modular can be "dropped in" to where you took out the original thing, without significant alteration or reconfiguration.

**So, it expresses a one-shot, effortless replacement of a part.**

In this case, the syntax of the two LaTeXes is similar enough that you can switch over without having to update your code.

Comment: great answer, why not visit here since 2014?

Comment: @YumiTada: I've been here plenty since 2014.

Comment: Your reputations is of 872 comparing with 125k of SO.

Comment: @YumiTada: My reputation on SO is 251k, not 125k.